# captureVideoで取得した動画ファイルをLocalStorageにコピーする方法

Tags: monaca, cordova

MonacaクラウドでiPhone向けのアプリを試作中です。

captureVideoで動画撮影したファイルを
LocalStorageのPERSISTENT領域に保存したいのですが、方法がわからず行き詰っています。

iPhone5でcaptureVideoで取得したファイルのパスを見ると

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/・・・

となっており、PERSISTENTともTEMPORARYとも異なる領域にありgetFileのやり方がわかりません。

できればAndroidでも動くような行儀のいいやり方でやりたいと思っています。

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

一つ回避方法を見つけました。
captureVideoで返ったファイルのパスをURIに変換し、getFileではなくresolveLocalFileSystemURIを使ってFileEntryを取得し、PERSISTENT領域に移すことができました。

しかしこの方法は回りくどく正攻法ではないように思われることと、LocalStorage内のパスをURIに変換してくれる機能が無さそうなので自前で環境依存性の高いコードを書くことになってしまい、ベストな解ではないと思っています。